# Managed array of UIView using some method

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, uiview, uiimageview

Hello I am noob in Xcode and I want to ask

I have array of UIView's with one image

```
NSInteger i;
for (i=0; i<CARD_AMOUNT; i++) {
    [cardArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"]];
}
```

and I want to draw it and then to do different things on each (move...etc) 
or I must create 10 variables of UIImageView?

Answer (score 0):

Could use a bit more explanation of the app you're trying to build, but essentially if you're wanting to display many different cards on one view (let's say, a game of solitaire) - you'll want to create many UIImageViews. *Well, from an pure design perspective, you'd probably want a different class called `CardView` which knew how to render itself*

So, if you wanted many different views all with one image, something like this:

```
for(int a=0; a<CARD_AMOUNT; a++) {
    UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"]];
    [cardArray addObject:view];
    // and maybe you'd want to set the frame locations, or add them to your current view as subviews, or .. 
}
```

To address the comments, your custom CardView might have something like this (there's ways to optimize, but the general concept isn't too bad):

```
- (void)setRank: (int)rank andSuit:(int)suit {
    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"card-%d-%d.png",rank,suit];
    self.rank = rank; self.suit = suit;
}
```

or, better yet (since a card's rank won't change) - some `initWithRank: andSuit:` method.. dunno.

There's probably 10 other ways to design this.

Comment: yes, i want to create solitaire game, but i can't understand how i can manipulate my images from array

Comment: You may be starting off too big. I'd start myself by building a custom UIView called CardView or something, which knew how to render itself based on a given suit and rank (you could have it custom draw itself, or reference 1 of 52 image names you bundle in the app). Once you can have 1 card on a view cycling through different images (just one card), then create and manage an array of those cards.

Comment: Just an aside, it may be more memory efficient to only allocate memory for the cards that are currently visible only - not the entire deck.